# How to properly handle files upload using Node.js Express backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, google-cloud-storage, multipart

I decided to use [**`ng-flow`**](https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow), an Angular implementation of [**`flow.js`**](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js) at front end to handle files uploading, I then picked **`multer`** as middleware to receive the files.

I did the most simple middleware setup for multer:

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './temp_uploads/'}))
```

Got a `/POST upload` route and I'm now logging to console what's being received:

```
app.route('/upload').post(function(request,response,next){

    console.log(request.body)
    console.log(request.files)
    // Response code and stuff then ...
});
```

So the outputs are :

```
{ flowChunkNumber: '1',
  flowChunkSize: '1048576',
  flowCurrentChunkSize: '1606857',
  flowTotalSize: '1606857',
  flowIdentifier: '1606857-IMG_20140807_153553jpg',
  flowFilename: 'IMG_20140807_153553.jpg',
  flowRelativePath: 'IMG_20140807_153553.jpg',
  flowTotalChunks: '1' }
{ file: 
   { fieldname: 'file',
     originalname: 'blob',
     name: 'c12d6f8d4950e48eee21b43f8ee4344a',
     encoding: '7bit',
     mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
     path: 'temp_uploads/c12d6f8d4950e48eee21b43f8ee4344a',
     extension: '',
     size: 1606857,
     truncated: false,
     buffer: null }}
```

Actually everything is being saved at my server, under `/temp_uploads` as it's supposed to. But **files won't keep their names and not even extension**. I wonder what I should do to configure it all good and even prevent problems at my server.

Just in case, I'll explain what I wanna do with the files. After receiving, I'll store them to Google Cloud Storage Platform. Then I will mail those files as attachments, if files are bigger than 15 MB I'll include a link to download at the mail.

At **`flow.js`** site they show this PHP snippet for handling files at server, but as I have a poor PHP background translating code isn't so reliable option to me:

```
$config = new \Flow\Config();
$config->setTempDir('./chunks_temp_folder');
$file = new \Flow\File($config);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    if ($file->checkChunk()) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 Ok");
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        return ;
    }
} else {
  if ($file->validateChunk()) {
      $file->saveChunk();
  } else {
      // error, invalid chunk upload request, retry
      header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
      return ;
  }
}
if ($file->validateFile() && $file->save('./final_file_name')) {
    // File upload was completed
} else {
    // This is not a final chunk, continue to upload
}
```

I'd like to make code more effective and actually doing the job making reliable implementation, how should I improve it?

Answer (score 1):

> Actually everything is being saved at my server, under /temp_uploads as it's supposed to. But files won't keep their names and not even extension. I wonder what I should do to configure it all good and even prevent problems at my server.

You can get control over naming by following the example at multer README.md. I've included it below:

```
app.use(multer({
    dest: './uploads/',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + Date.now()
    }
}))
```

Looks like there are many other hooks as well.

See also [cloud-storage](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cloud-storage) module. You can use that to push data to Google.

[abstract-blob-store](https://github.com/maxogden/abstract-blob-store) and [google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/maxogden/google-cloud-storage) built on top of that would be even better fit. It would allow you to stream the files directly to Google without having to use an intermediate storage.

Comment: So the objects at fieldname wil contain original name, right?

Comment: I expect `filename` argument would contain something useful. You can always dig into multer source to see what it's exactly doing. :)

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/4848ca846bbaf3cee5acd9f4c4bbecb12cfd1826/index.js#L28 .

Comment: `filename` IS the value of `originalname`