# File upload issue with multer using node js and mongodb server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I created one application using node js, react js, mongodb. I want to upload files using multer, but the file does not upload. I shared the code blocks I wrote for frontent and backend with you. How can I register imgae to mongodb successfully using multer. I searched a lot on the Internet, but I am very confused. I would be very happy if it could help.

**model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

newSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    email : String,
    password : String,
    img:{
        type: String
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', newSchema)
```

**backend - routes/ index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const User = require('../models/index')
const router = express.Router()
//
const multer = require('multer')
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4')
const DIR = './public/';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, DIR);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const fileName = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
        cb(null, uuidv4() + '-' + fileName)
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg") {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(null, false);
            return cb(new Error('Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!'));
        }
    }
});

//

/* find all users */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    User.find({},(err,data) =>{
        res.json(data)
    })
})

/* find user by id */
router.get('/:id',(req, res) =>{
    User.findById(req.params.id, (err, data) =>{
        res.json(data)
    })
})

/* delete user by id */
router.delete('/:id',async (req, res) =>{
    await User.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    res.json({'message':'deleted'})
})

/* create */
router.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
    const user = new User({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password,
        img: url + '/public/' + req.file.filename
    })

    user.save(()=>{
        res.json(user)
    })
})

/* update */
router.put('/:id', async (req, res)=>{
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.is, req.body)
    res.json({'message':'updated'})
})

module.exports = router
```

**frontend -react side /App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: [],
            id: 0,
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            img: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        try {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api')
                .then((res) => {
                    this.setState({
                        users: res.data,
                        id: 0,
                        name: '',
                        email: '',
                        password: '',
                        img : ''

                    })
                })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    nameChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        })
    }

    emailChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            email: event.target.value
        })
    }

    passwordChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            password: event.target.value
        })
    }

    submit(event, id) {
        event.preventDefault()
        if (id === 0) {
            axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api', {
                name: this.state.name,
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
                img: this.state.img
            }).then(()=>{
                this.componentDidMount()
            })

        } else {
            //axios.put('http://localhost:8080/api/'+id, {
            axios.put('http://localhost:8080/api/${id}', {
                name: this.state.name,
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
                img: this.state.img
            }).then(()=>{
                this.componentDidMount()
            })
        }
    }

    deleteUser(id) {
        try {
            axios.delete('http://localhost:8080/api/' + id)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.componentDidMount()
                })
            console.log('Deleted successfully.')
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    editUser(id) {
        try {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/' + id)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data)
                    this.setState({
                        id:res.data._id,
                        name: res.data.name,
                        email: res.data.email,
                        password: res.data.password,
                        img: this.state.img
                    })
                })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s6">
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => this.submit(e, this.state.id)}>
                        <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <i className="material-icons prefix">person</i>
                            <input value={this.state.name} onChange={(e) => this.nameChange(e)} type="text" id="autocomplete-input"
                                   className="autocomplete" required/>
                            <label htmlFor="autocomplete-input">Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <i className="material-icons prefix">mail</i>
                            <input value={this.state.email} onChange={(e) => this.emailChange(e)} type="email" id="autocomplete-input"
                                   className="autocomplete" required/>
                            <label htmlFor="autocomplete-input">Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <i className="material-icons prefix">vpn_key</i>
                            <input value={this.state.password} onChange={(e) => this.passwordChange(e)} type="password" id="autocomplete-input"
                                   className="autocomplete" required/>
                            <label htmlFor="autocomplete-input">Password</label>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light right blue" type="submit" name="action">Submit
                            <i className="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>
                        <div>
                            <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="col s6">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name Surname</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Password</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {this.state.users.map(user =>
                            <tr key={user._id}>
                                <td>{user.name}</td>
                                <td>{user.email}</td>
                                <td>{user.password}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button onClick={(e) => this.editUser(user._id)}
                                            className="btn waves-effect waves-light green" type="submit" name="action">
                                        <i className="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button onClick={(e) => this.deleteUser(user._id)}
                                            className="btn waves-effect waves-light red" type="submit" name="action">
                                        <i className="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t good practice to upload files (that have been converted to strings) to MongoDB. I would recommend using a filesystem or a service such as AWS S3 for that.

The reason it isn’t good practice is that services such as S3 are much more scalable because the images are stored on multiple servers and services such as S3 can run behind a [content delivery network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) which store copies of the images on servers all over the world.

To store files on the filesystem, see [How to properly handle files upload using Node.js Express backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452950/how-to-properly-handle-files-upload-using-node-js-express-backend).

If the files are small and you wish to store their content on MongoDB, see [How do I save a file to MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907509/how-do-i-save-a-file-to-mongodb).

Comment: how can i implement that?

Comment: Which part, S3 or saving small files as strings in MongoDB?

Comment: actually my goal is to write a small user photo to mongodb, one for each user. Something simple.

Comment: How small are the images? Are they resized on the front or back end?

Comment: size is not set, but I will not add very high size photos. I am doing this project for trial purposes, but I could not register to mongodb officially.

Comment: Where are you planning on hosting the project? If localhost or on a virtual machine with filesystem support (example: DigitalOcean), perhaps you should consider storing the images on the filesystem.

Comment: my project will remain localhost. I do not use it in an institutional sense, I try to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the header - `"Content-Type: "multipart/form-data"` in your axios `post` request. After that you should be able to find your files in `req.files` in your Express route.

After that you should be able to upload the files to MongoDB.

Nonetheless you should consider using a service like AWS S3 or Filestack to store your files, while storing only the URL in your MongoDB.

Hope this helps!